# How to plot 2D time series with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have data in the following form:

```
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(40),
                y=rnorm(40), 
                t=rep(sample(1:10, replace = F), times=4), 
                v=rep(1:4, each=10))

ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~v)
```

[image: TimeSeries]

I want to add  line (ideally with an arrow indicating direction) connecting the points ordered by the time variable (t).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the previous answer, having the final arrow is sometimes confusing, here is a tip to add arrows between each points.

2 solutions:

1. The arrow reaches the next point

[image]

```
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(40),
            y=rnorm(40), 
            t=rep(sample(1:10, replace = F), times=4), 
            v=rep(1:4, each=10))

d = d[order(d$t),]
d = d[order(d$v),]

d$y_arrow = c(tail(d$y, n=-1), NA)
d$x_arrow = c(tail(d$x, n=-1), NA)
d$y_arrow[d$t == 10] <- NA
d$x_arrow[d$t == 10] <- NA

ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, group = v)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~v) + 
geom_path()+ geom_segment(aes(xend=x_arrow, yend=y_arrow), 
arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm"))) + theme_bw()
```

2. The arrow is the half-way

[image]

```
d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(40),
            y=rnorm(40), 
            t=rep(sample(1:10, replace = F), times=4), 
            v=rep(1:4, each=10))

d = d[order(d$t),]
d = d[order(d$v),]

d$y_arrow = c((tail(d$y, n=-1) + head(d$y, n=-1))/2, NA)
d$x_arrow = c((tail(d$x, n=-1) + head(d$x, n=-1))/2, NA)
d$y_arrow[d$t == 10] <- NA
d$x_arrow[d$t == 10] <- NA


ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, group = v)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~v) + 
geom_path()+ geom_segment(aes(xend=x_arrow, yend=y_arrow), 
arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm"))) + theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it was surprisingly easy using `geom_path`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x=rnorm(40),
                y=rnorm(40), 
                t=rep(sample(1:10, replace = F), times=4), 
                v=rep(1:4, each=10))

d <- arrange(d, t)
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path(arrow=arrow()) +
  facet_wrap(~v)
```

[image]